# Does "/* (non-javadoc)" have a well-understood meaning?

Tags: java, comments, javadoc

Does `/* (non-javadoc)` have a meaning, beyond pointing out to the reader of source code that a comment block is intentionally not a Javadoc comment? Lately I've seen a lot of code that looks like this:

```
/*
 * (non-javadoc)
 *
 * This method converts widgets to gizmos
 */
public Foo bar() {
   ...
```

Is this an established convention of some kind? If so, what does it mean (beyond the obvious literal meaning) and when is it used?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [info I could find](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/278495/), this was to fix a bug in older versions of the JavaDoc tool (or more likely older version of Eclipse's processing of JavaDoc comments) that would not display the correct documentation for a method that overrides the method of a parent class.

As noted by Konstantin, Eclipse's override template includes this text.

Comment: FYI: http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg34412.html is now a dead link.

Comment: @MaxNanasy Apparently Eclipse changed forum systems a while back and they didn't redirect individual posts.  New location is https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/278495/

Answer (score 16):

It doesn't have an established meaning besides being a comment. The formatting is result of common Eclipse code formatting templates, which explains its commonality.