# /* (non-javadoc) meaning

Tags: java, syntax, comments, javadoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does “/* (non-javadoc)” have a well-understood meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597329/does-non-javadoc-have-a-well-understood-meaning)

What does the following statements mean?

```
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * Standard class loader method to load a class and resolve it.
     * 
     * @see java.lang.ClassLoader#loadClass(java.lang.String)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Answer (score 29):

Javadoc looks for comments that start with /****.
By tradition, method comments that are not intended to be part of the java docs start with "/* (non-Javadoc)" (at least when your dev environment is Eclipse).

As an aside, avoid using multi-line comments *inside* methods. For example, avoid this:

```
public void iterateEdges()
{
  int i = 0;

  /* 
   * Repeat once for every side of the polygon.
   */
  while (i < 4)
  {
  } 
}
```

The following is preferred:

```
public void iterateEdges()
{
  int i = 0;

  // Repeat once for every side of the polygon.
  while (i < 4)
  {
    ++i;
  } 
}
```

The reason is that you open the possibility to comment out the entire method:

```
/*
public void iterateEdges()
{
  int i = 0;

  // Repeat once for every side of the polygon.
  while (i < 4)
  {
     ++i;
  } 
}
*/

public void iterateEdges()
{
  // For each square edge.
  for (int index = 0; index < 4; ++index)
  {
  }
}
```

Now you can still see the old method's behaviour while implementing the new method. This is also useful when debugging (to simplify the code).

Comment: What a redundant convention. :O

Comment: I'm always tempted to delete these Eclipse-generated comments, since they sometimes comprise a large proportion of many simple classes' textual content without providing any benefit.  They don't convey any information that a reasonable IDE or a programmer's common sense can't infer (it's got an @Override annotation, I *know* where I can find the JavaDocs for it...).

Answer (score 27):

I have seen this message generated by Eclipse when the programmer asks Eclipse to add a Javadoc comment to some code in a location where [EDIT: Eclipse thinks] the Javadoc tool will not actually *use* it.

A common example is the implementation of a method in an interface implemented by the class (which in Java 6 needs the @Override annotation).  Javadoc will use the javadoc placed on the method in the *INTERFACE*, not the one provided in the implementation.

The rest of the comment was most likely written by a person that did not know this.

Comment: @Tom, no need to put the programmer down. in Java programming it is close to impossible to be an expert on all relevant technologies.

Comment: Actually, if you provide the comment with `/**`, it would be used instead of the interfaces method. (And having it in the source even if not used has the benefit to be there when one reads the source.)

Comment: Thanks @PaŭloEbermann for a great tip!

Answer (score 12):

```
/*
 * This is the typical structure of a multi-line Java comment.
 */

/**
 * This is the typical structure of a multi-line JavaDoc comment.
 * Note how this one starts with /** 
 */
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just a normal comment. The note means, if you create a manual, base of javadoc, this text won't be added.

Comment: @simpleuser because ( I assume that ) the "real" doc comment it's placed elsewhere.